# How to set <spring:message> as argument into another <spring:message> tag?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to pass `<spring:message>` containing property value where property key generated dynamically?

```
 <spring:message  code="label.form.${ myform.myHandler.Suffixvalue} //<- Need to pass it as argument
 //Property -> label.form.person=person
 //Property -> label.form.father=father

<font color="red" class="boldText">
    <i title="<spring:message code="label.mylabel" arguments="${arg}" />" ></i>
 </font>

 label.mylabel=I am a great {0}
```

How to manage it in Spring MVC?